# Asymptotic analysis of this statement.

Tags: asymptotics

Say if I have some expression $\frac{h}{k^2}$ or $\frac{h^2}{k}$ and I send both $h,k \rightarrow 0$. Can I say that the expressions tend to zero without further explanation?

When we send these constants to zero are we sending them to zero at the same speed? Or even assuming similar initial conditions?  E.g if in the first expression we were to assume that $k^2 < h \implies \frac{1}{k^2} > \frac{1}{h}$ and hence 
$$\frac{h}{k^2}>\frac{h}{h}=1$$

This leads me to believe that we must provide a further explanation.  i.e that the restriction $k^2 > h$ must hold in order for $\frac{h}{k^2}\rightarrow 0$

> Am I thinking about this correctly or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, you need to say something about the relative rates in order to understand limits of functions of both variables, in general.

Comment: $f(h,k)/g(h,k)$ can have any limit as $h,k \to 0,0,$ without knowing what $f,g$ are.

Comment: Same rate h = k, what does that give you? how about $h = k^2$ or $h=k^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: I see, so in order to say that the first statement converges as the variables tend to zero I would have to mention the conditions that result in convergence. This makes sense. Thanks as always!